# Read multiple files to string with javascript

Tags: javascript, file, text

My application read a specific .txt file on the server and writes the content in a string (array)

```
filename = "textfile01.txt"
$.get(filename, function(datafil) {
    var bookings = datafil.split("\n");

    //Display
    $("#divname").append(bookings);

});
```

It works good, but i'd like to add to my array the content of all the text files in that directory.
I thought to use regular expressions, but i don't know how apply them. Something like "load all `/textfile\d\d\.txt/`files in the datafil string".

So i can load textfile01.txt, textfile02.txt and so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client has no access to a directory's list of files. Which makes it impossible to 'directly' get a list of possible files to download.

If you keep a consistent filename protocol (like textfile01.txt, textfile02.txt etc...) you can easily just go through a loop counting upwards.

```
var totalFiles = 99;
for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++){
    var number = (i < 10) ? '0' + i : i;
    var filename = "textfile" + number + ".txt";

    $.get(filename, function(datafil) {
        var bookings = datafil.split("\n");

        // Display
        $("#divname").append(bookings);
    });
}
```

Or if you'd rather use files where each is named differently, a simple array with filenames would suffice.

```
var files = ["hello.txt", "world.txt"];
files.forEach(function(file, index){
    $.get(file, function(datafil) {
        var bookings = datafil.split("\n");

        // Display
        $("#divname").append(bookings);
    });
 });
```

Mind you, the $.get() functions will be called pretty much simultaneously, which means there's no guarantee the content of the files will be appended to #divname in the same order.

Comment: In reality, my files will be named "prefix_numbersForDay_NumbersForTime.txt", so prefix is known, i can do a "for" cycle for Day, because i'll read just recent files, but i can't think to do a "for" cycle to find all the files. NumbersForTime is 4 digit

Comment: Then I am afraid you're out of luck with JavaScript. You'll have to resort to a server-side solution with this. Like a .php that reads a directory's contents and returns a JSON string when called with JQuery's .get().